# Vue2 Tree Select Ajax call failing to load options

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, vuejs2, axios

I am Trying to use this library to get dynamic input element in the form of a tree
https://riophae.github.io/vue-treeselect/#basic-features

My options will be generated through an ajax call to Laravel backend.

My Vue2 Component Code is like this,

```js
<template lang="html">
  <div>
    <div class="" >
      <treeselect :multiple="true"  :options="options"   :flat="true" :sort-value-by="sortValueBy"  :default-expand-level="1"
      placeholder="Try selecting some options."        v-model="value"   />
      <pre class="result">{{ value }}</pre>
    </div>

</div>
</template>
<script>
import Treeselect from '@riophae/vue-treeselect'

function tests(id) {
  var data = [];
  axios.get('/standards/' + id + '/tests')
    .then(function(response) {
      data: response.data;
    });
  return data;
}

let called = false

export default {
  components: {
    Treeselect,
  },

  data() {
    return {
      value: null,
      options: tests(1)
      sortValueBy: 'ORDER_SELECTED',
    }
  },
  methods: {
    loadRootOptions(callback) {
      axios.get('/standards/1/tests')
        .then(response => rootOptions = response.data);
    },
  },
}
</script>

<style src="@riophae/vue-treeselect/dist/vue-treeselect.min.css"></style>
```

Laravel Backend is like this

```
public function tests($id)
    {
        $tests = [['id'=>'a','label'=>'sandeep'],['id'=>'b','label'=>'sandeep']];
        return $tests;
    }
```

The JSON response from backend is correct. 
The problem is in using this tree select library to load options dynamically through an ajax call.

KIndly Help with proper code, since I am new to using Vue.

Answer (score 1):

if you still need help, not sure if this was available 8 months ago.
All this code is available at https://vue-treeselect.js.org/#delayed-loading

```
  <treeselect
        v-model="value"
        :options="options"
        :load-options="loadOptions"
        :auto-load-root-options="false"
        :multiple="true"
        placeholder="Open the menu..."
    />



 import { LOAD_ROOT_OPTIONS } from '@riophae/vue-treeselect'
 import { LOAD_CHILDREN_OPTIONS } from '@riophae/vue-treeselect'
```

And then in methods add loadOptions

```
        loadOptions({ action, parentNode, callback }) {

            if (action === LOAD_CHILDREN_OPTIONS) {
                        parentNode.children = [ {
                            id: 'child',
                            label: 'Child option',
                        } ]
                        callback()
            }

            if (action === LOAD_ROOT_OPTIONS) {

                this.options =  [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' ].map(id => ({
                    id,
                    label: `option-${id}`,
                }));

                callback();
            }
        },
```

Comment: I am loading even root elements dynamically, the important thing is to always call the callback :)